# How can I prevent a VirtualKeyboard from coming up on a particular form?

Tags: firemonkey, android-softkeyboard

Delphi 10.3, Firemonkey.
I have a form on which it is a real nuisance to have a virtual keyboard coming up.
(There is a tMemo which does various things on being clicked, and after a couple
of clicks the virtual keyboard arrives.)
How can I prevent this on that particular form please?

Comment: maybe to not use a Tmemo on this form? why a Tmemo if you don't want to show keyboard ?

Comment: I actually have about a dozen forms in one programme, and it would be a lot neater to be able to get the keyboard when I want it (eg double-click on an editable item) and not get it when it gets in the way!  Surely there must be some way of having decent control over the wretched thing!